# drupal field list data

Tags: 7, entities

I have created a custom field list, but of all documentation I have read, I can't find a clear example on how to add data on the list.

The code so far is this:

```
/**
 * Adds field.
 */
function _my_installed_fields() {
  $t = get_t();
  return array(
    'my_dropdown_list' => array(
      'field_name' => 'my_dropdown_list',
      'label' => $t('Select an item'),
      'type' => 'list_text'
    )
  );
}
/**
 * Adds instances.
 */
function _my_installed_instances() {
  $t = get_t();
  return array(
    'my_dropdown_list' => array(
      'field_name' => 'my_dropdown_list',
      'type' => 'list_text',
      'label' => $t('Select an item'),
      'widget' => array(
        'type' => 'options_select'
      ),
      'display' => array(
        'example_node_list' => array(
          'label' => $t('Select n item'),
          'type' => 'list_text'
        )
      )
    )
  );
}
```

I need to let only one value to be selected and saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add cardinality and settings parameters:

```
  function _my_installed_fields() {
    $t = get_t();
    return array(
      'my_dropdown_list' => array(
        'field_name' => 'my_dropdown_list',
        'label' => $t('Select an item'),
        'type' => 'list_text',
        'cardinality' => 1,
        'settings' => array(
          'allowed_values' => array(
            1 => 'One',
            2 => 'Two',
            3 => 'Three',
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
```

Comment: That worked, I have the 3 example options, but I still have the "none" option too. How to I delete that option? Where did you find those information? I would like to seek the proper documentation

Comment: I have just used search by `'type' => 'list_text'` and checked the examples. As an option you can use Features module: add field manually from admin UI, save this field in feature and export feature, in generated Features module you will find properly code of your field.

Comment: That you that helped, I want forward with my project, do you mind to give a look to my next issue? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197793/use-module-to-change-custom-type-theme